# input line height makes input scrollable on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I noticed this weird behavior on IE when I set a `line-height` value on an `input` field. You can [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pWMQ/58/), try to write some text in the `input` field, then click and hold the mouse button on it and move the mouse up and down: the `input` scrolls by the space of the `line-height`. Is there any workaround for this?

```css
    input {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      line-height: 2;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll appears because the **padding + font-size values are lower** than the one used for the `line-height`;

The line-height:2; has an higher value so it displays inside the input text and gives the scrolling effect when on focus.

You can try to calculate it accordingly to your input-text font size and set a value of line-height in pixels so to have an **absolute line-height** and not relative.

For example if your `font-size` is 14px try to set the line-height to

14px + 5px padding top + 5px padding-bottom which is equal to 24px.

See if setting it to 24px solves your issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with padding, you can remove it but the beahviour is the same. And why only on IE?

Comment: IE10 is known to have issues in line-height calculations when relative line-height is applied. Especially for input fields and textareas. Not sure in depth how it interpretes those values and why applying a relative line-height breaks.

Comment: They removed conditional statements from IE10 and added a lot of fixes but also bugs here and there :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra height value for vertical height of the input box: 
`height: 2em;`